# Problem when trying to access NSArray

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0

I'm trying to initialize an NSArray in the loadView method. And when I initialize it, it has a certain address in the memory.

Then when I touch the screen I call the refresh method. When I debug the blends array here, it has the same address, but the content is {(int)[$VAR count]} objects...

Here is my code:

```
@implementation MCPickerViewController
#pragma mark Overriden methods

- (void)loadView {
    [super loadView];

    blends = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Piepje", @"Paapje", nil];

    pickerView = [[MCPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
    pickerView.delegate = self;
    [self setView:pickerView];
}

#pragma mark Delegate methods for MCPickerView

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self refresh];
}

#pragma mark Personal methods

- (void)refresh {
    NSLog(@"count: %i", [blends count]);
}
@end
```

I hope someone can help me, cause I'm stuck for a long time!

Thnx!!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what the problem is but you do need to retain the blends array (and release it somewhere).

I'd also recommend you read [Apple's memory management guide](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html) to understand when you should retain, release, autorelease, etc.

Comment: yes "{(int)[$VAR count]}" means that the object is no longer valid (it tried to get the length of the array but it wouldn't work); which means it was released. instance variables definitely need to be retained